# Interop between MSXML and .Net using COM+

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com+

I need to create a .Net C# component with these two requirements:

1. Giving an XML and an XSL path as input parameters should return an HTML string.
2. The XSLT engine needs to be implemented using the MSXML XSLT processor <sup>*</sup>

Using `MSXML` via [COM Interop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop) could be an option but I've found this scary knowledge base article on the subject that says:

**815112 INFO: Use of MSXML is Not Supported in .NET Applications**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815112

> MSXML uses threading models and garbage-collection mechanisms that are
>   not compatible with the .NET Framework. Using MSXML in .NET
>   applications through COM interoperability can result in unexpected
>   problems that are difficult to debug.

Could using `MSXML` in out-of-process `COM+` package be a safer way to access `MSXML` from a .NET application?
As stated in my requirements, I don't need to handle `MSXML` classes or interfaces as Input/Output parameters but just plain vanilla strings.

<sup>* The code base consists of thousands of XSL files that run fine on `MSXML` XSLT engine (MSXML 4.0) but give more than an error with the pickier `System.xml` .Net library.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand why not use one of the builtin xml libraries? You're saying that system.xml is given you trouble. Perhaps it would be easier to debug the problem you are having with System.Xml. Alternatively couldn't you "preprocess" the files if you are having (most likely) formatting issues?

Comment: I agree 100% with @MaximGershkovich- I can't help but imagine that fixing your problem with the built-in XML libraries will result in a vastly more stable and better-performing codebase.

Comment: @systempuntoout *what* error?  XML/XSLT is a very well-defined system- you shouldn't be seeing variation between the libraries.  It's not that we are trying to be unhelpful- more like trying to point you in the direction of the elevator instead of the stairs.

Comment: @Chris _you shouldn't be seeing variation between the libraries_ -  welcome to the real world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create an [out-of-process COM+ application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then use the classes in the [`System.EnterpriseServices` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.aspx) or a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735856.aspx) (I'd go with this, personally) to connect to the COM+ application.

Of course, this means you'll have to use some other technology *besides* .NET to host your component, but it's probably the easiest way to get process isolation and interoperability with .NET out-of-the-box.